# Різниця між "конусний" і "конічний"

Tags: вибір-слова

Мейнарович і Кратко [стверджують](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=conical&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on), що

**conical** = ['kɒnɪkl] ко́нусний; коні́чний

Але в чім різниця між цими двома словами?

Мені здається, що *конічний* це такий, що має *конусну* форму, наприклад, *конічна гірка*. А *конусний* це такий, що належить конусу, наприклад, у конуса є форма - *конусна форма* і вона належить конусу. Та не можу це обґрунтувати.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Словники

«Словник української мови» каже таке:

- > [КОНІ́ЧНИЙ](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=43527&page=1375), а, е. Прикм. до ко́нус. <…> // Який має форму конуса. <…>
- > [КО́НУСНИЙ](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=43808&page=1385), а, е. 1. Прикм. до ко́нус. <…>
  >
  > 2. Який має форму конуса; конічний. <…>

Тобто множини значень цих слів однакові.

Але в *конічний* оте «який має форму конуса» позначено частиною основного значення, а в *конусний* — другим значенням. (Можливо, з цього випливає те, що для *конічний* це притаманніше значення, а для *конусний* — більш другорядне; а можливо — нічого не випливає.)

#### Про походження

Оте *-ус* у латині (а також *-ос* і подібні в грецькій) — це відмінкове закінчення, що використовується лише в певних формах. У нас його традиційно відкидають: і у власних іменах (*Αναξαγορ**ας*** → *Анаксагор*, *Plini**us*** → *Пліній* і т. ін.; десь було навіть окреме запитання про це), і здебільшого в загальних назвах (*ἀρχιερε**ύς*** → *архієрей*, *degenerat**us*** → *дегенерат* тощо); я припускаю, що випадки, коли воно зберігається, спричинені найчастіше малою довжиною слова — якщо відкидати такі закінчення в коротких словах типу *вір**ус***, *пол**юс***, *град**ус***, то значно збільшується ймовірність омонімії. Утім, при утворенні похідних слів від іменників, де це закінчення таки збереглося, воно часто знов-таки відпадає: *еп**ос*** → *епічний*, *град**ус*** → *градація*, *косм**ос*** → *космічний*, *мод**ус*** → *модальний*, *пол**юс*** → *полярний*.

Але не завжди: *вір**ус*** → *вір**ус**ний*, *пол**юс*** → *пол**юс**ний* (і *полярний*).

Тобто з одного боку — ніщо не зобов'язує ці слова (*конічний* і *конусний*) мати різні значення; вони можуть бути всього-на-всього наслідком різних шляхів боротьби з омонімією: в одному використовується складніший суфікс *-ічн-*, в іншому не прибирається оригінальне закінчення *-ус*. З іншого — ніщо не забороняє цим словам із часом розійтися в значеннях, як це трапилося з *полюсний* і *полярний*.

#### Про семантику суфіксів

[Людмила Сидоренко, «Суфіксальна деривація ад'єктивів у технічній термінології»](http://journlib.univ.kiev.ua/index.php?act=article&article=1953):

> - «належний тому чи виготовлений з того, на що вказує твірна основа» — *N + -н(ий)*, <…>;
> - «такий, що позначає відношення до чогось» — *N + -ичн(ий) / -ічн(ий)*;

Це начебто має бути аргументом у бік Вашої теорії: *конусний* — належний конусу, *конічний* — стосовний конуса.

<sub>Але практика і словники не підтверджують це:

• за словниками: щонайменше слову *конічний* притаманні обидва значення, щонайбільше — обом словам;

• за вжитком: *[конусна форма](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac8&queryselector=cqlrow&cql="%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9"+"%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0"&default_attr=lemma)* вживається значно рідкіше за *[конічну форму](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac8&queryselector=cqlrow&cql="%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9"+"%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0"&default_attr=lemma)* (навіть нормалізувавши відносно частот вживання слів *конусний* і *конічний*, маємо 6/59≈0.10 і 65/522≈0.12), *[конусний](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac8&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)* уживається і як «що має форму форму конуса»: *конусна яма*, *конусний горбик*, *конусна виїмка*).</sub>

#### Висновки

Не знаю.

Можливо, воно було б по-Вашому, якби не низький суспільний попит на розрізнення цих значень.